# Why when using sonarqube-webhook behind a reverse proxy is giving HTTP Status 404 – Not Found?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a Jenkins server behind a Nginx reverse proxy and I'm trying to use the `sonarqube-webhook` plugin. When I try to access by ip everything works, but when I try by reverse proxy not.

nginx.conf

```
server {

    server_name devops.close-upinternational.com;
...
location / {
            proxy_pass http://cup-jenkins:8080;
            proxy_http_version                 1.1;
            proxy_cache_bypass                 $http_upgrade;
            # Proxy headers
            proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection        "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host              $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
            # Proxy timeouts
            proxy_connect_timeout             3600s;
            proxy_send_timeout                3600s;
            proxy_read_timeout                3600s;
        }
```

I can access Jenkins login page by http://devops.close-upinternational.com/. I also exposed **50000** and **8080** ports on docker compose.

docker-compose

```
cup-jenkins: 
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-cup-jenkins
    image: lserillo/cup-jenkins:latest
    container_name: cup-jenkins
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /data/DevOps/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /data/DevOps/jenkins_home/downloads:/var/jenkins_home/downloads    
    ports:
      - 50000:50000
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - wso2_bridge
```

I can get response from webhook by http://ip:8080/sonarqube-webhook/

But if I try by proxy http://devops.close-upinternational.com/sonarqube-webhook/ it doesn't work.

What happens with SonarQube plugin when is tried to use behind a reverse proxy?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is the useless repetition of tag information. The title should be clear and descriptive enough that its content is clear to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results. For help writing a good title, see [ask].